# Filtrar base de datos al cargar csv usando Pandas

Tags: python, base-de-datos, pandas, csv

**Yo cargo el csv asi
pero tengo mucho datos en quiero filtrar Columunnas, pero esta tiene un nombre(estados unidos, canada, colombia, etc) quiero tomar los datos de una ciudad especifico, que tome los datos de siguen en las otras columnunas con que son asi(Regiones,tiendas, tiempo)**

```
df = pd.read_csv("./sample_data/Global_Mobility_Report.csv")

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
df3=df[["country_region","date","sub_region_1","grocery_and_pharmacy_percent_change_from_baseline"]]
print(df3.query("country_region =='Colombia'and sub_region_1 =='Bolívar'"))``
```

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido(a) a la comunidad, te recomiendo hacer el [recorrido de bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer la sección [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Tu pregunta no es muy clara, ¿Hay algún problema al importar los datos? o ¿Quieres saber si hay alguna forma de "filtrar" los datos al mismo tiempo de ser importados?

Comment: Quiero saber si hay forma de filtrar los datos ya importados

Comment: La respuesta corta es si hay, ¿Podrías editar tu pregunta y agregar un ejemplo de los datos de entrada (Como texto, no como imagen), por ejemplo las primeras 20 líneas y como esperarías obtenerlos a la salida?

Comment: Podrias suministrar mas informacion acerca de tus datos por favor?